# How to start aiogram bot and aiohttp webserver together?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiohttp, aiogram

I have aiogram v3 bot that runs in polling mode, I need to add a handler to process requests from exteranl application, i use aiohttp server that listens for external requests, process it and send notification to bot users:

```py
import asyncio
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher
from aiohttp import web


app = web.Application()

async def bot_start():
    bot = Bot(TOKEN, parse_mode='HTML')
    dp = Dispatcher()
    await dp.start_polling(bot)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(bot_start())
    loop.run_until_complete(web.run_app(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=5555))
```

so bot starts polling, but web server is not running, please help to start both processes within single project.

PS. bot must run in polling mode, not a webhook.

**SOLUTION**:

need to run both apps as async func in separate tasks:

```py
async def bot_start():
    bot = Bot(TOKEN, parse_mode='HTML')
    dp = Dispatcher()
    await dp.start_polling(bot)

async def webserver_start():
    app = web.Application()
    runner = web.AppRunner(app)
    await runner.setup()
    site = web.TCPSite(runner, "127.0.0.1", 5555)
    await site.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    task1 = loop.create_task(bot_start())
    task2 = loop.create_task(webserver_start())
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(task1, task2))
```

Comment: That's not the solution, as it won't handle shutdown cleanly, and you shouldn't be using the low-level asyncio APIs without fully understanding them. I gave the solution below, which describes how the web application should be in control of the loop and the bot code should be tied to the lifecycle of that app.

Answer (score 1):

This is explained in the docs: https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_advanced.html#complex-applications

Use cleanup_ctx:

```
async def run_bot_task(_app):
    task = asyncio.create_task(bot_start())

    yield

    task.cancel()
    with suppress(asyncio.CancelledError):
        await task  # Ensure any exceptions etc. are raised.

app.cleanup_ctx.append(run_bot_task)
```

Then run your app as normal with `web.run_app()`, without messing with the loop.

Note that a fatal flaw in your code is that `web.run_app()` is not an async function, it's the entry function for an asyncio application. i.e. It replaces `asyncio.run()` in a typical asyncio application.